# Can you add a condition into a lambda function?

Tags: python, function, lambda, logic

I have the following code:

`clean_tweets['tweet'] = clean_tweets['tweet'].apply(lambda x: remove_noise(x))`

I want to add the logic *add the condition that remove_noise is done only if the tweet is string*

Is it possible to achieve this, are there any alternative ways of getting this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a so-called ternary expression in Python, such as:

```
(result_if_clause_is_true) if (clause) else (result_if_clause_is_false)
```

In your specific case:

```
lambda x: remove_noise(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x
```

Anything more complex than an if/else operation should become its own function, however.

Note that this expression can be used in many other places, not only in lambdas:

```
x = y**2 if y < 10 else y/2  # assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

- `lambda x: remove_noise(x)` is just `remove_noise`
- You should probably add the logic into `remove_noise` function:

  ```
  def remove_noise(x):
      if not isinstance(x, str):
          return x # or None or whatever other value
      # handle the case where x is a string
  ```

As a whole:

```
def remove_noise(x):
    if not isinstance(x, str):
        return x # or None or whatever othe value
    # handle the case where x is a string

clean_tweets['tweet'] = clean_tweets['tweet'].apply(remove_noise)
```